# How to get the name of the month with year in a single statement in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, datetime

Currenctly i have a column called month and year as show in the picture below.

[image]

Can i know how to get the Name of the Month with the Year as the outcome in a single query

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below statement to generate like the above output.

```
SELECT (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(CAST (month AS TEXT), 'MM'), 'Month') || ' ' || year) AS "expected_outcome";
```

For short month:

```
    SELECT (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(CAST (month AS TEXT), 'MM'), 'Mon') || ' ' || year) AS "expected_outcome";
```